# Arrays is sorted but two indexes are not correct

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am having some trouble with my code. I understand how to use the sort method but want to be able to use other methods to solve this.

```
        int[] nums = {1,5,3,8,9,12,45};
        System.out.println("Before sorted: "+Arrays.toString(nums));

       
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
        {
            
            if (nums[i] > nums[i+1]) {

                nums[i+1] = nums[i];
           }

        }
        System.out.println("After sorted: "+ Arrays.toString(nums));//will print [1, 5, 5, 8, 9, 12, 45]
//instead of [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 45]
    }
```

Comment: Study https://stackabuse.com/sorting-algorithms-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

So your code is not doing sorting but rather just moving a few values around.  To correctly swap two values to try to sort you need a temporary variable.  So to swap integers A and B while sorting you need a third integer to hold the variable being overwritten.

```
Temp = A
A = B
B = Temp
```

swaps A and B.  From the swapping you can build up to sorting (and there are a few easily found, sorting algorithms).

Comment: B would equal B in this example, B = Temp